# Nested indexing in a loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, vectorization

I have a `for` loop performing the current operation:

```
T = [1,1,1,4,5,6,3];
A = [20,15,4,21,14,3];
l = length(T);

% how can we vectorize this?
for(i = 1:l)
    A(T(i)) = A(T(i)) + 1;
end
```

Simply put, it uses the `T` vector as a list of indices to increment on the `A` array in a particular order. For instance, the first element in array `A` will be incremented 3 times (corresponding to the 3 ones in `T`), while the rest get incremented once, 2 doesn't get incremented. The resulting changes to `A` are thus:

```
A = [23,15,5,22,15,4];
```

However, ideally I would like to avoid a `for` loop here. Before I tried:

```
A(T) = A(T) + 1;
```

This didn't work; MATLAB just ignores the repeated indices. Is there someway I can perform the operation in the `for` loop by vectorisation or some other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[q,w] = hist(T,0:numel(A));
A(w(q>0)) = A(w(q>0)) + q(q>0);


A =

23    15     5    22    15     4
```

Explanation:

You can use `hist` to know how many time each index occurs in `T`. 
Since indexes are integers, you can specify the ranges from 0 to the number of elements of A.

`Hist` will then return two vectors:

q is the number of occurrences of each index:

```
q =

0     3     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
```

w are the indexes themselves:

```
w =

0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Then you just take the indexes that occur at least once `w(q>0)` as the indexes of A to be updated, and you update those indexes by the number of occurrences `q(q>0)`

Answer (score 3):

With [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
T = [1,1,1,4,5,6,3];
A = [20,15,4,21,14,3];
res = A + accumarray(T(:), 1, [numel(A) 1]).';
```

Comment: `A + accumarray(T(:), 1, [numel(A) 1])'`   otherwise Matlab complains:  When SUBS is a column vector, the third input SZ must be of the form [N 1].

Comment: Also `s = accumarray(T(:),1).'; w = 1:numel(s); A(w) = A(w)+s;`